# Transposing a column of data sets into a new row whenever it finds a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, transpose

I'm pretty new to excel and creating macros/VBA so here I am, asking for help.

I have this data set and is currently in 1 column only:

|  |
| --- |
| 8/5/2021 08:47:37 |
| Temp 1 |
| Temp 2 |
| Temp 3 |
| Blank Cell |
| 8/5/2021 08:47:44 |
| Temp 1 |
| Temp 2 |
| Temp 3 |

And I can transpose them from columns into a row which will appear like this:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/5/2021 08:47:37 | Temp 1 | Temp 2 | Temp 3 | *Blank Cell* | 8/5/2021 08:47:44 | Temp 1 | Temp 2 | Temp 3 |

What I want to do is, transpose into a new row whenever the value is "date and time".

It should look something like this:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/5/2021 08:47:37 | Temp 1 | Temp 2 | Temp 3 |
| 8/5/2021 08:47:44 | Temp 1 | Temp 2 | Temp 3 |

Comment: Please, read read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). About your question, take all data into array , loop trough it and paste acording to your needs.

Comment: I totally understand your point. I've been researching for days now and I just can't find the right terms or words to research about how can I do my process. But thank you a lot for the recommendation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I won't be writing the code for you, but here's a rough outline of what you need.

- a [loop](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) down all cells in that column
- within that loop, if the cell [is a date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) then select that cell and the 3 below it using `union()` and `range.offset()`
- Copy the relevant cells (one row) and then use `range.pastespecial Transpose:=true` on the column next to the top of the range (details [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/value-paste-pastespecial/) if you scroll down a bit)
- delete the used-up 3 or 4 rows before continuing the loop
- once the loop is done, delete the original column with leftover data in it, as everything got pasted across to another range.

That, plus google search, should be all you need to fix your problem!

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the guidance and encouragement. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This will check for the existence of a '/' character in the cell.

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim a1 As Range: Set a1 = Range("A1")
    Dim a2 As Range: Set a2 = a1.Offset(1)
    Dim b As Range: Set b = Range("B1")
    Do Until Intersect(a2, ActiveSheet.UsedRange) Is Nothing
        If InStr(a2, "/") > 0 Then
            b.Resize(, a2.Row - a1.Row) = Application.Transpose(Range(a1, a2.Offset(-1)))
            Set a1 = a2: Set a2 = a1.Offset(1): Set b = b.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set a2 = a2.Offset(1)
        End If
    Loop
    b.Resize(, a2.Row - a1.Row) = Application.Transpose(Range(a1, a2.Offset(-1)))
End Sub
```

Before.

[image]

After.

[image]